# No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager registered NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, razor-pages, .net-6.0, identity

Getting this error for some re

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[TenDSecurity.Domain.Identity.Models.AppRole]'
> has been registered.
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType)

This is a snippet of my program.cs

```
var connectionName = "connectionStringName";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionName);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, providerOptions => providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(3)));
builder.Services
    .AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
        //User Settings
        //options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        //options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        //Sign In settings
        //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;

        //Lockout Settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services
    .ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        // Cookie settings
        //options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        //options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });'
```

custom user Identity Contexts

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, short, AppUserClaims, AppUserRoles, AppUserLogins, AppRoleClaims, AppUserTokens>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Exception raw

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager\`1[TenDSecurity.Domain.Identity.Models.AppRole]' has been registered.
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)    
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<CreateActivateInfo>b__1(ViewContext context)  
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyActivator\`1.Activate(Object instance, TContext context)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(Object page, ViewContext context)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPageActivator.Activate(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderLayoutAsync(ViewContext context, ViewBufferTextWriter bodyWriter)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable\`1 statusCode)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable\`1 statusCode)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|22_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)  
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)    
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync() 
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)    
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
    at TenDSecurity.Web.Razor.Middleware.UserDestroyerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, UserManager\`1 userManager, SignInManager\`1 signInManager)
        in C:\Users\jbalman\source\repos\TenDSecurity.ERM\TenDSecurity.ERM\TenDSecurity.Web.Razor\Middleware\UserDestroyerMiddleware.cs:line 33
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

A note  : that the UserDestroyerMiddleware is just what makes sure the user is login

I'm at a loss why this doesn't work now for my old razor pages app but still works a the new Blazor UI I'm working on ( same database)

Comment: And where the exception happens?

Comment: added the exception output sorry it happens when trying to hit the login page

Comment: It seems to be a problem of DI. It might help if you post this as an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/new/choose)

Comment: i have this problem too..

Comment: I ended up having to recreate a new project and migrate over my view files, I'm still not sure what got corrupted, to be honest, but I was unable to recreate the issue to submit to GitHub and my existing repo was work-related so not something I could directly share.  if you are able to submit your code for review maybe create a ticket here was my bug report for reference https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43327